# how to change styling on the same line within a <div>

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a part of a web page (incorporating Bootstrap CSS) that contains a `<div>` with the id "drop-zone" that I pick up later in javascript to implement drag-and-drop functionality:

```
<div id="drop_zone">
    <p style="color: darkgray">Drop</p>
    <p style="color: black">test.txt</p>
    <p style="color: darkgray"> here</p>
</div>
```

I have the `<p>`s in there because I want to vary the styling across this single line, but if I use the code above, or if I swap the `<p>`s for `<div>`s, the code renders on multiple lines like so:

> Drop
>
> **test.txt**
>
> here

when I really want it to look like:

> Drop **test.txt** here

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but any thoughts here?

Comment: I would highly recommend learning some more about HTML especially since you are using something like Bootstrap so that you get a better understand of what it is actually doing.

Starting with learning how inline, block, and inline-block works.
http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/
http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`<span>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4) instead of `<p>`.

Answer (score 4):

`<p>` and `<div>` are both block elements which will be display their contents on a separate line by default. You'd be better off using a `<span>` which will display its contents inline.

```
<div id="drop_zone"><span style="color: darkgray">Drop</span><span style="color: black">test.txt</span><span style="color: darkgray"> here</span></div>
```

You should really consider moving all the styles into a stylesheet, too, instead of having them defined in `style` attributes like you have as this will make changing the styles easier as your page gets more complex.

Answer (score 2):

try the below in your divs or p tags or better yet create a class that has this property :

```
display : inline;
```

or

```
display : inline-block;

<div id="drop_zone" style='display:inline;'><p style="color: darkgray; display:inline;"> Drop </p><p style="color: black; display:inline;"> test.txt </p><p style="color: darkgray;  display:inline;'"> here</p></div>
```

This is the [jsdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sVV3/)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `<p>` is a block-level element, so by default it will cause a line-break .. you can replace it with an inline element (`<span>`) or set the `<p>` display to either inline or inline-block

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `<span>` instead of `<p>`

```
<div id="drop_zone"><span style="color: darkgray">Drop </span><span style="color: black">test.txt</span><span style="color: darkgray"> here</span></div>
```